# Flutter video_player multiple videos

Tags: flutter, video-player

Flutter video_player package has this bug, when you play 4-5 videos, after that it hangs, does not play any more videos. Looks like in the backed its not releasing the controller and I see messages in Android Studio like, "Failed to initialize decoder: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc"

I am using the same controller and loading new video files from assets.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
final String url = 'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4';

VideoPlayerController.network(url, videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it woked for me. May Allah bless You, Me & All of us.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `_controller.dispose()`, when moving on to the next video. And make sure to use the same video controller.

[Here](https://github.com/brownsoo/flutter_video_list_sample) is an example.

Comment: have you tried using this in a listview builder?

Comment: From what I know is that you can only run certain (2-3) controllers at the same time. In a ListView, where probably many controllers are **displayed and connected** at the same time it would make huge performance issues. If you mean that only one controller is actually running at the same time, using `dispose` should work.

Comment: I'm using dispose but ListView.builder calls dispose a time after the widget is off the screen. Automatic keep alives and cacheExtent dont work.
Let me try on a real device and see

Comment: That's expected behavior! ListView only builds the widgets that are being shown and discards everything else (calling `dispose`). What you want to do is call the widget again after it is being shown again (maybe safe at the last playing minute etc). Please create a new question if you have further problems with this.